# paper.js support for SVG Tiny standard

Tags: svg, paperjs

Is there a way to restrict paper.js to only the SVG Tiny standard?  The current output is more verbose than necessary and some of our downstream processes only allow SVG Tiny.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in way to do this from Paper.js.
The SVG export options are listed [here](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#exportsvg), maybe some of them will help you getting closer to the expected format.
But you will have to transform the output yourself.